# Tough goniometric inequality (different period)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I'm trying to solve this inequality:
$\dfrac{1 - 2 \sin(x)}{2 \cos(x / 2) + \sqrt{3}} \leq 0$

Using the standard method of setting $\text{numerator} > 0$ and $\text{denominator} > 0$ and then comparing the signs I get stuck, because the results have different periods ($2\pi$ vs $4\pi$) and I cannot draw them on a single circumference.

Any hints?

Comment: Just an idea: replace $\sin(x)=2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2)$. Now the periods match, at the cost of having both sine and cosine in the expression.

Comment: I think that the word "goniometric" is even tougher than the inequality itself (thanks Wikipedia!).

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: Eheh sorry, I'm not a native speaker! In my language we have a distinction between "goniometry" (I don't know if this is the correct term in english) and trigonometry. The latter is goniometry applied to triangles.

Comment: @coffeemath: I tried that too, but then the numerator become too hard to solve, IIRC.

Comment: @rubik At first I thought that you were mistaken. I immediately asked to The Oracle (Wikipedia), and surprise: the word do exist!, so you don't need to sorry at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that
$$\dfrac{1 - 2 \sin(x)}{2 \cos(x / 2) + \sqrt{3}} \leq 0$$
precisely when $1 - 2 \sin(x)$ and $2 \cos(x / 2) + \sqrt{3}$ are non-zero and have different signs, or when $1 - 2 \sin(x)=0$.

Now for each of the following, determine the values of $x$ for which it is satisfied (if there are any):

- $1-2\sin(x)<0$
- $1 - 2 \sin(x)=0$
- $1 - 2 \sin(x)>0$
- $2 \cos(x / 2) + \sqrt{3}<0$
- $2 \cos(x / 2) + \sqrt{3}>0$

and from this, determine the values of $x$ for which the conditions are met.